# Compare hashed password to validate if passwords are matched

Tags: php, security, hash, blowfish

I use blowfish method to hash the passwords from the user when they're signing up.

In the signup form, there is "Enter Password" box and "Confirm Password" box.

So, to check if the passwords are matched, I used hashed versions to compare. But then, it doesn't seem to match.

Please see the code below...

get values from the super global variables and hash them.

```
$hashed_password = password_encrypt($_POST['password']);
$conf_hashed_password = password_encrypt($_POST['conf_password']);
```

call the function

```
 passwords_match_check($hashed_password, $conf_hashed_password);
```

Defined function

```
function passwords_match_check($hashed_pw, $conf_hashed_pw){
    global $errors;
    if($conf_hashed_pw != $hashed_pw){
        $errors['pws_no_match'] = "Passwords do not match";
    }
```

}

This code always says passwords do not match even if I do know passwords are same...

So, where I have gone wrong... ?

Is it OK, if I just used the values without hashing to compare ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/password_verify) (both included in php 5.5+). And if you're on 5.3 - 5.5, use [password-compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) backwards compatibility library.

A custom `password_encrypt()` function is un-necessary and very likely less secure then the built-in one. So just use the built-in one.

Comment: Thanks.. currently I think I have 5.4.3.. Ok, I'll look into that... :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you share the password_encrypt function it's hard to say.
If the method seeds the encryption uniquely both hashes will be different.

( Could be the reason of your failed check. )
Why not check the raw input instead of the hashed?

Comment: I checked with raw inputs... It did work without any problem. This happened after I used hashed versions...

Comment: I assume if you print / var_dump the hashed variables to your screen you will get two different hashes on screen. Please share what the method password_encrypt does (tried to lookup on php.net but seems to be an unknow function)

Comment: I printed them on the page and they were different. password_encrypt is a custom function I wrote and it uses blowfish method and salt to hash the passwords

Comment: Well there you go. If you share your password_encrypt  function we could comment on that.